# Regex to compare 2 strings upto first mismatch and output the matching and mismatching parts

Tags: regex, perl

Assume, I have 2 strings.

```
$file1_out="astra.abs ::nerve :  Costa.br_.cotAlev.ksaf.large.props.fault_check"
$file2_out="astra.abs ::nerve :  Costa.br_.cotBlev.ksaf.large.props.fault_check"
```

You can see that the only difference is A and B in cotAlev & cotBlev in the 2 strings. I would like to compare them and get 2 new variables

```
$part1="astra.abs ::nerve :  Costa.br_."
$part2=".ksaf.large.props.fault_check"
$var="cot_lev" ###removed the mismatching character
```

That is break till first unequal word and split into 3. How can I do this use regex in PERL

I'm new to perl and used loop concept common in C here to solve this. I've achieved this by breaking strings into characters into comparing each and then combining them accordingly into 3 variables. But i was told that there were easier ways to do this. There are lot of comparisons to be made, so speed does matter...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it seems like substrings would do the trick without regex here?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Text::Diff](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aDiff), it may do what you try to do already.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this could be handled with regular expressions. You said you handled this with C looping. You could do something similar in Perl.

```
my @file1_chars = split //, $file1_out;
my @file2_chars = split //, $file2_out;
```

This will split up your strings into an array with each entry in the array being a separate character. Now you can loop till you find your first mismatched character:

```
my $first_mismatched;
for my $char_num ( (0..$#file1_chars) ) {
    if ( $file1_chars[$char_num] ne $file2_chars[$char_num] ) {
        $first_mismatched = $char_num;
    }
}
if ( defined $first_mismatched ) {
    say "The two strings stop matching on character # $first_mismatched";
}
```

This will print out:

```
The two strings stop matching on character # 34
```

The `$#file1_chars` is the last array index of `@file1_chars`. The `(0..$#file1_chars)` indexes from the first index entry to the last index entry of `@file1_chars`.

You could reverse this to go from the last character to the first character:

```
my $last_mismatched;
for my $char_num ( reverse (0..$#file1_chars) ) {
    if ( $file1_chars[$char_num] ne $file2_chars[$char_num] ) {
        $last_mismatched = $char_num;
    }
}
if ( defined $last_mismatched ) {
    say "The two strings restart matching on character # $first_mismatched";
}
```